# SpriteKit rotation when collision does not work

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have this [code](http://codepaste.net/oo9ct7) to simulate collision, but my objects wont rotate. So collision seems works good, but without rotation.

Comment: There is nothing in your code to show you are trying to rotate anything?!

Comment: @sangony, I am using physic body I suppose it should rotate it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is strange.

I would say it is because you have set friction to 0.0, nothing is gripping to it to spin it.

Also check the "allowsRotation" property on the physics body to ensure it is set to TRUE.